# HTACCESS Rewrite rule merging query parameters into 1st parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I am struggling to get the $_GET parameters to sit under their respective key.

I have the following HTACCESS rule:

```
RewriteRule ^view/new/(.*)/?(.*)/?(.*)/?(.*)$ vehicles/new-details.php?man=$1&model=$2&trim=$3&engine=$4 [QSA]
```

When accessing this page, I am temporarily printing out the $_GET array:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

This returns:

> `Array ( [man] => BMW/3-Series/SEL/EVO-3.0-TFSI [model] => [trim] =>
>   [engine] => )`

Whereas it should return:

> `Array ( [man] => BMW [model] => 3-Series [trim] => SEL [engine] => EVO-3.0-TFSI)`

The *man* parameter is required, whereas all others are optional.

Not sure what is happening here. Could it be the fact that I have made parameters optional in the rewrite rule?

Comment: Can you give few examples of source and target URis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^view/new/(.*)/?(.*)/?(.*)/?(.*)$ vehicles/new-details.php?man=$1&model=$2&trim=$3&engine=$4 [QSA]
> ```

`(.*)` will take in all characters into each capture group, you want to qualify this to take in all characters up to the `/`.

So replace `(.*)` with `([^/]*)` which is telling the mod_rewrite to *"Take any character until you meet a `/`"*;

```
RewriteRule ^view/new/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ vehicles/new-details.php?man=$1&model=$2&trim=$3&engine=$4 [QSA]
```

This should give you the result you expect.

Edit: [**Read here**](https://serverfault.com/questions/386059/apache-mod-rewrite-multiple-variables) for a far fuller answer!